Minimal polynomial given root
In a certain exercise I have been asked to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = \beta^2 + \beta$, with $\beta: f(\beta) = 0, f(x) = x^3+3x^2-3$. I tried by computing $\alpha^2,\alpha^3$ or $\beta f(\beta),\beta^2f(\beta)$, but I don't find any relationship between linear combinations of these terms and using an expresion such that in terms of $\alpha$ is zero. Could somebody give me a hint?

In which field are you working? $\mathbb Q$?

Yes, that's where I'm working in.

Another method is to use the "determinant trick". I will sketch it here but not calculate everything in detail.
The polynomial $f$ is irreducible by Eisenstein, so $[\mathbb Q(\beta) :\mathbb Q] = 3$. Thus $\{1, \beta, \beta^2\}$ is a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $\mathbb Q(\beta)$. Consider the $\mathbb Q$-linear map
$$L_{\alpha} \colon \mathbb Q(\beta) \to \mathbb Q(\beta), \qquad x \mapsto \alpha x.$$
Calculate the matrix $M$ of $L_{\alpha}$ with respect to the basis $\{1, \beta, \beta^2\}$. One has
$$M \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \beta \\ \beta^2\end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \beta \\ \beta^2\end{pmatrix},$$
so $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $M$. So the characteristic polynomial $\chi_M$ of $M$, which has degree $3$, has $\alpha$ as a root. The argument given in mathcounterexamples.net's answer shows that $\chi_M$ is irreducible.
Edit:
Here is the explicit computation.

 We have $\beta^3 = -3\beta^2 + 3$ and thus $\beta^4 = -3\beta^3 + 3\beta = 9\beta^2 + 3 \beta - 9.$

This yields

$$L_\alpha(1) = \alpha = 0 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot \beta + 1 \cdot \beta^2,$$
$$L_\alpha(\beta) = \alpha \beta = \beta^2 + \beta^3 = 3 \cdot 1 + 0 \cdot \beta  - 2 \cdot \beta^2,$$
$$L_\alpha(\beta^2) = \alpha \beta^2 = \beta^3 + \beta^4 = -6 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot \beta + 6 \cdot \beta^2.$$

Thus the matrix of $L_\alpha$ with respect to $\{1, \beta, \beta^2\}$ is

$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3 & -6 \\ 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 1 & -2 & 6\end{pmatrix}.$$

Its characteristic polynomial is $\chi_M = X^3 - 6 X^2 + 9 X  - 3.$


Could you show the polynominal $\chi_M$ of degree $3$ from your method?

@NN2 Done, although the question asks about a hint.

No, the question asked for a hint to find the minimal polynomial…

@NN2 And I presented a method for finding that polynomial. I feel like you're just splitting hairs. I won't argue over this, so this is my last response.

As $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ according to Eisenstein's criteria, $[\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q] = 3$. As $3$ is a prime number and $\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\beta)$, either $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$ or $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q] = 3$. $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$ is impossible as it implies $[\mathbb Q(\beta):\mathbb Q] \le 2$. Therefore the degree of $\mu_\alpha$, the minimal monic polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$ is equal to $3$. And $\mu_\alpha(\beta^2+\beta)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $6$ having $\beta$ as a root. So $f$ is a factor of $\mu_\alpha(\beta^2+\beta)$ as a polynomial in $\beta$.
You can then find $\mu_\alpha(x)= x^3+cx^2+bx+a$ using the fact that the reminder of the polynomial long division of $\mu_\alpha(x^2+x)$ by $f(x)$ is equal to zero.

I would appreciate it if the downvoter could comment on why she downvoted.

Certainly, those who cannot read and appreciate excellent responses vote negatively. +1.

Your answer is incomplete because you proved only that $\text{deg}(f) \ge 3$ but you didn't prove $\text{deg}(f) = 3$ is achievable.

@NN2 $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q] = 3$ means $\deg \mu_\alpha = 3$. Also, it would help if you didn't use $f$ here, that is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$.

@mathcounterexamples.net The question asked clearly that "asked to find the minimal polynomial of..". So, you should show the polynomial. Even if you can prove that the polynomial exists, it is not sufficient.

@NN2 You should read the question better before providing wrong comments.... The question states Could somebody give me a hint?!

The hint must be related to " find the minimal polynomial", not  to "prove the existence of this polynominal".
